Need help installing Tutor OpenEdX(version Quince or Redwood) on a server (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud)
I'm familiar with installing Tutor OpenEdX for local development, but I'm now trying to set it up on a cloud server like AWS, Azure, or Google Cloud. Could anyone provide detailed steps or guidance on installing and configuring Tutor OpenEdX(version Quince or Redwood) on a server?
If you have successfully set up Tutor OpenEdX on any cloud platform, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share the process or point me to relevant resources.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Asking for tutorials is considered Off-topic in SO. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Follow these steps to install Tutor edx -
Tutor Edx
